# ¿Por qué [0-9]{8} coincide cuando hay más de 8 dígitos?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el siguiente código, para comprobar una expresión regular:

```js
var a = /^\+569[0-9]{8}/;
var n = "+56957069354";
console.log(a.test(n));
```

Quiero que tenga un `+` al principio seguido de `569` y seguido de **8 dígitos máximo**, pero si pongo más de 8 aún asi devuelve `TRUE`, ¿por qué?

Comment: Creo que te devuelve TRUE, porque al llegar al octavo caracter igual se esta haciendo el [match](https://regex101.com/r/9NQ07A/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 dígitos máximo. Es decir, entre 0 y 8 dígitos:

```
\d{0,8}
```

Pero esto aún podría coincidir con 8 dígitos en el medio del texto, y que haya más dígitos después. Para eso, nos garantizamos que el número termine ahí. Es decir, que coincida con el final del texto (con `$`).

Expresión regular:

```
/^\+569\d{0,8}$/
```

Demo:

```js
var regex = /^\+569\d{0,8}$/;

//Pruebas
for (let n of ["569", "+569", "+5690", "+56957069354", "+569570693540", "+56957069354000"]) {
    let resultado = regex.test(n);
    console.log(n, "-->", resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al no especificar un final para la expresion regular `$/`, esta hara `match`, con todo lo que tenga al menos 8 digitos en adelante.

Por lo tanto, el error que tienes ocurre porque no estas definiendo un final para la expresion regular.

Lo solucionas asi:

#### 8 digitos

```js
var a = /^\+569[0-9]{8}$/;
var n = "+56957069354";
console.log(a.test(n));
```

#### Mas de 8 digitos

```js
var a = /^\+569[0-9]{8}$/;
var n = "+56957069354000";
console.log(a.test(n));
```

Comment: En la pregunta dice "*8 dígitos máximo*", y probablemente busque `\d{0,8}`

Comment: Hola ivan, a qué te refieres con hacer match

Comment: Debes documentarte un poco mas al respecto, en mi opinion, hacer `match` significa **que concuerde la expresion con el texto escrito, es decir, que coincidan con el patron o bien con la expresion regular**.